# How to retrieve message as a String from MessageKit

Tags: swift, chat, message, messagekit

I am using MessageKit to make a basic chatting app. However, I wanted to do something with the text of the latest sent message.

This is an example of what I want:

```
print("This is what I was talking about:\n\n", newMessage.kind)
```

I get:

```
text("Hi StackOverflow!")
```

However, I wish to get only this String `"Hi StackOverflow"`. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch statement. For example,

```
var message = ""
switch newMessage.kind { 
case .text(let messageText): 
    message = messageText
default:
     break
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53787852/swift4-messagekind-has-no-member-url) is similar to yours, and may be useful

Answer (score 0):

```
func getTheMessageText(messageKind: MessageKind) -> String {
    if case .text(let value) = messageKind {
        return value
    }
    return ""
}
```

Usage: Call this method to get the message as a string like

```
let messageType:MessageType = messageList[indexPath.section]
getTheMessageText(messageKind: messageType.kind)
```